# predicate not working in join lambda expression

Tags: c#, entity-framework, linq, predicatebuilder

I have using `PredicateBuilder` class to dynamically creating `Where` clause in LINQ statements.

Following is my code which is **When using predicate**

```
var predicate = PredicateBuilder.True<tbl_login>();
predicate = predicate.And(x => x.DAT_LOGIN_TIME >= startDate && x.DAT_LOGIN_TIME <= endDate);`
var data = context.tbl_login.Join(context.tbl_user, x => x.LNG_USER_PRIMARY_ID, y => y.LNG_USER_PRIMARY_ID, (x, y) => new
{
    userID = x.LNG_USER_PRIMARY_ID,
    loginTime = x.DAT_LOGIN_TIME,
    ageGroup = y.INT_AGE_GROUP
}).Where(predicate)
  .Select(x => new 
    { 
      userID = x.userID, 
      ageGroup = x.ageGroup 
    }).Distinct().ToList();
```

It gives me compile time exception `cannot convert from System.Linq.Expressions.Expression<System.Func<JoyRydeAnalysis.Data.tbl_login,bool>>' to System.Linq.Expressions.Expression<System.Func<AnonymousType#1,int,bool>`

What i am missing?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your predicate is a predicate for `tbl_login`. But here, you're projecting to an anonymous type:

```
(x, y) => new
{
    userID = x.LNG_USER_PRIMARY_ID,
    loginTime = x.DAT_LOGIN_TIME,
    ageGroup = y.INT_AGE_GROUP
}
```

That predicate can't be applied to that projection.

I suspect you *may* want to apply the predicate earlier instead though:

```
var data = context.tbl_login
                  .Where(predicate)
                  .Join(...)
                  .Select(...)
                  .Distinct()
                  .ToList();
```

Note that at this point, your `Select` will be redundant, as you can just change the projection in the `Join` call.

It's also note clear why you're using `PredicateBuilder` at all, to be honest. You're only joining `PredicateBuilder.True` with a single expression - so you can just use:

```
var data = context.tbl_login
                  .Where(x => x.DAT_LOGIN_TIME >= startDate && x.DAT_LOGIN_TIME <= endDate)
                  .Join(...)
                  .Select(...)
                  .Distinct()
                  .ToList();
```